# After clicked on Link Count One Down (-1) from Total of Count JavaScript - MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I have page ,where im showing all messages and in header im showing Total of messages by counting them and im looking for something with javascript or MVC ,when user click on link (its means message be opened) count one down (-1) of total count which is messages and then use localstorage or Cookies to remember the count for next time, when user coming back to check their messages.
Can anyone please help me or point me in the right direction!
Thanks in advance :)

For example : lets say i have 14 messages , when user click on link i should be 13

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult Messages(RMAHistory m2)
    {
        string EmailID = Session["Email"].ToString();
        ViewBag.CountMSG = (new DbNamespace().Besked.Where(x => x.KundensEmail == EmailID).Select(f => f.KundensEmail).ToList().Count);

        var bla7 = (from RB in db.Besked

                    where RB.KundensEmail == EmailID

                    select new RMAHistory.Comment_List
                    {   
                        id = RB.ID,
                        MSG = RB.MSG,
                        se = RB.Seen,
                        Date = RB.Date,
                        Forfatter = RB.Writer,
                        KundensEmail =RB.KundensEmail,
                        Id = RB.RMAID,
                        MSGType =RB.MSGType
                    });

        m2.Comment_Lists = bla7.ToList();
        return View(m2);
    }
```

View:

```
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-7 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header" data-background-color="purple">
                   <span class="category">(You have @ViewBag.CountMSG New Messages)</span>
                </div>
      <div class="content">
         @if (!Model.Comment_Lists.Any())
            {
             <div class="bs-callout bs-callout-danger">
               <h4>You Do not Have New Messages</h4>
             </div>
            }
                    else
                    {

     foreach (var item in Model.Comment_Lists)
                  {
            if (item.se == "Kunde")
                   {
                     <div class="bs-callout bs-callout-success message">

                       <div class="col-xs-3 text-right">

                      <a target="_blank"  href="/Account/RMADetails?id=@item.Id" id="@item.id"  class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn-icon btnChangestu"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a>

                       </div>

         <h4><i class="fa fa-bookmark-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Message number @item.Id</span></h4>
         <span class="text-muted"><small> @item.Date.ToString("dd/MMMM/yyy")</small></span><br />

<span class="text-muted status"><span> @item.MSGType</span></span>

 <input type="hidden" name="ChangeStu" id="ChangeStu" value="read massage" />

                                </div>

                            }
                        }
                    }

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('.btnChangestu').click(function () {


            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            if (!id) {
                return;
            }

            var button = $(this);
            var status = $(this).closest('.message').find('.status');


            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("UpdateMSGStatus", "Account")',
                data: {
                    IDMSG: id,
                    ChangeStu: $("#ChangeStu").val()
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (result) {

                    if (result) {
                        status.text("read message");
                        button.removeData('id')
                        console.log("Ok")
                    } else {
                        // display error?
                        console.log("error");
                    }



                },
                error: function () {
                    console.log('something went wrong - debug it!');
                }
            })

        });


    });
</script>
```

Comment: Why show messages that the user has already read?

Comment: Note also you `ViewBag` is not necessary - you can just use `@Model.Comment_Lists.Count`

Comment: @StephenMuecke its good question and you right ,when they read the messages im gonna hide message

Comment: yes i know , its beacuse it will be like linq if im gonna use count in view ,and beacuse of dat i keep it in controller.

Comment: You query appears to be returning all messages for the user? What property to you have that indicates if a message has been read, and how is it set?

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes based on user email

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178081/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-7-seconds).